# Xamarin.Forms Android: Save/Store some data on OnHandleIntent event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, intentservice

**Xamarin.Forms Droid project:** How to store some data on `OnHandleIntent` event. I'm trying save data in `Application.Current.Properties`. When application active/open there is no problem, but when application closed data not saved. Any help would be appreciated. Below code example:

```
[Service]
public class GCMIntentService : IntentService
{
    //other methods

    protected async override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        //Some code for push notification
        Application.Current.Properties.Add("key", "value");
        Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xamarin.Forms Android: Save/Store some data on OnHandleIntent event

The `Application.Current.Properties` is just a dictionary of objects you can stick anything you want in there, including your own classes which will get serialized, and the properties collection is read from a file  and this is done automatically.

However, the entire dictionary is serialized together in a file, an exception during reading or deserialization of that file will be catched and just leave you with an empty Properties collection.

**Solution :**

You could use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to **Save/Store** some data, as the document said :

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. **This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).**

In `Xamarin.Android`, You'll need to get the instance of [ISharedPreferences](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.ISharedPreferences/) and use that to update/change/delete preferences. As [Tom Opgenorth](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference) said, there are a couple of ways to get an instance of `ISharedPreferences` :

- **Activity.GetPreferences**

  would get you preferences specific to that activity. Probably not what you want.
- **Context.GetSharedPreferences**

  can get you application level preferences.
- **PreferenceManager.DefaultSharedPreferences**

  will give you an ISharedPreference instance for a given context.

The actual saving is done by an instance of `ISharedPreferencesEditor`, which you get get by invoking the method `ISharedPreferencesEditor.Apply()`. Here is an example :

Save your data :

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
editor.PutString("number", "Value");
editor.Apply();
```

Restore your data :

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
var a = prefs.GetString("number", "null");//"null" is the default value
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @YorkShen, I will give a try, and then will tell the result.